# PCB trace and antenna matching

Tags: antenna, impedance, trace

I'm designing a pcb with a Sub-1GHz chip and I'd like to add a chip antenna on my design.
I choosed one of the johanson technology products, especially this one
https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/antennas/0900AT43A0070.pdf
In the datasheet I see many references of matching network close to antenna.

The question is: Is really needed to place a matching network if the anntena's feed line has exactly the same impedance as antenna's input? (50 Ohm in my case).

Comment: *Thinks* maximum power transfer, *thinks* high standing wave ratio (SWR) for a mismatch, *thinks* manufacturer's recommended circuit so I'd say yes it is.

Comment: If the distance is less than 1/10 the wavelength there isn't much point

Comment: If the impedance in both two sides (pcb trace and input of antenna) are identical, there would be maximum power transfer. Isn't there?

Comment: Yes, but they're telling you the matching network is needed to make the antenna have 50-ohm input impedance. They're also giving you the ability to tune the performance in case your pcb material is slightly off in dielectric constant (very common with low cost materials) or your geometry is slightly off from ideal, or some nearby conductor (like the housing of your circuit) affects the antenna.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I can't see the point that is mentioned in the datasheet. There's a note "General Specifications" that is mentioned the impedance at 50 Ohm. There's also a reference that reports that values will be different in someone's design. However, the matching network is explained as recommended, not required. And I was thinking that if this is mentioned in the case which the feed line might be different from 50 Ohm. In my case, though, as I mentioned above, my feed line has been constructed to meet 50 Ohm impedance.

Comment: Repeating the points made above, your antenna is designed to meet 50Ohm impedance. For various reasons it may not be 50 Ohm precisely. In these cases, you may or may not want the tuning network, depending on your mismatch. IMO, its better to design it and leave it unpopulated than needing one and not having it.

Comment: I think you just validate my first intuition, thanks!